# Reference writing in Latex

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

When I wanted to cite a paper in the past, I could receive the paper on Google Scholar and get its Latex item. But some are not searchable on Google.
For example, I saw this in other paper references:

> Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual, Intel
> Corporation, Apr 2012.
>
> Large Page Performance, VMware Inc., Palo Alto, CA, US, 2008.

The above two, how should I edit its Latex entry?

Comment: The solution here depends on several aspects. First of all it depends on the type of the references you want to cite: The first seems to be a manual of some kind. The second is not so clear to me, it could be a research paper, it could be single page of a website. Secondly, the solution depends on the output you want to see. Thirdly, the solution depends on the concrete bibliography style you are using.

Comment: If you want more tangible help, you need to tell us more about those three points.